# My GCP Account does not have an Organization & displays "No Organization" What are the drawbacks or negative impact of having No Org?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-workspace

We have 2 accounts that have super admin.

Account #1 signed up without Workspace.
Account #2 signed up with Workspace. 
Our application's project is under Account #1, but displays "No Organization." 
Our Primary Domain is verified under Account #2, and does have our Organization on it.
Do you think I should move the project from Account #1 to Account #2? 
Or attempt to delete/cancel Account #2, and try to move the primary domain & Organization?

Account #1 has a Firebase Project with Cloud Firestore, if that matters.

Comment: Move the project to Account #2. Make note of the billing accounts and payment accounts as you may want to update those project assignments and delete ones no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits are discussed [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#benefits_of_the_organization_resource):

```
You can get better control of your projects as there will be an organization admin and you can use org policies.
Reduced risk of losing a project.
Reduced risk on rogue administrators.
You can create folders and segment your organization, eg engineering and billing.
You can use inheritance at org level.
You get Workspace org features.
```

Comment: do you have a suggestion for my case? Thinking of moving my project from Account #1 to Account #2.

Comment: You are not tied to specific scenario, you can also [release](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#special_cases) a project under an org.

Comment: I tried to migrate my project from "No Org" to My Org on the other account, but the "migrate" button was greyed out, and I did not receive any error messages or any references to docs.

Comment: Assuming you are using the same email account make sure you are owner on project with no org, on project with org make sure you have project  creator role and billing admin role. Grey means you do not have permissions. If that fails you need to check [org policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#permissions_organization_policy).

Comment: Doing it through command line [gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID /
    --organization ORGANIZATION_ID] might also give you  a more meaningful error and tell you which permission you might be missing