# Disadvantages of having a GCP project without organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I found some problems on Google Cloud managing paths like /{organization}/{project-id} with some tools (mainly BigQuery with automated transformations).

Because of that, one approach is to create a project without organization (with a billing account connected), but I am not sure about which possible future problems this will imply.

The only disadvantage I see is that we wouldn't use the GCP organization structure to manage IAM permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only one project, having an organisation or no changes very little (some features aren't available, such as organization policies - but of course you don't have an organization!), hierarchical firewall rules, or security command center).

You will have a real difference if you manage several projects: IAM is a use case, Cloud Logging sink and asset inventory.

---

However, it's safer, and cleaner, to solve your previous issue with organization/project that you have previously than creating a standalone project.

Comment: Other benefits are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486172/my-gcp-account-does-not-have-an-organization-displays-no-organization-what-a/68486933#comment121043204_68486933